# How to make a custom NSView within a NSMenuItem becomeFirstResponder?

Tags: macos, cocoa, mouseevent, nsview, nsmenuitem

I have a custom NSView within a NSMenuItem (attached to a MenuBar) that respond to a mouseDown event. But I need to click twice on the custom view for the mouseDown function to be called, this is because the custom view should be first responder. And when I override the method acceptsFirstResponder in my CustomView Controller as indicated by the Cocoa Event Handling Guide, it does not work. What is the solution? Is it doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `NSView` method `acceptsFirstMouse:` to return `YES` for the event in question.  If you only want to accept the first mouse click for some types of events, you can do that by examining the event parameter passed in.  Unless there is something special about the NSMenuItem case in particular, this should be what you want; it's the standard Cocoa mechanism for this.  Note that this method is not the same as the `acceptsFirstResponder` method you have tried.  See Apple's doc for details.

Comment: Nice, I did not know this

Answer (score 1):

For reference I have just added to my custom view the following:

```
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstMouse:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    return YES;
}
```